# Azure Web Sites Custom DNS Limit

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If I need to set many hostnames for an Azure Web Site in reserved mode, I receive an error:

```
No CNAME pointing from www.xxxx.it to a site in a default DNS zone (or too many).
```

This error appears randonmly before I added the fourth entry, then it seems to persist, so I cannot add the fifth. This limit isn't mentioned anywhere in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

During preview the limit is set to 4 after I ran some test. However this could change as Windows Azure Websites will release for general availability.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure this out now. I already had it set to shared but thank you. I had to configure a * wildcard CNAME record with my DNS host. Not all providers support this. I went with Amazon AWS.